# How do i get a vector from gensim's translation_matrix

Tags: mapping, translation, gensim, word2vec

I have trained two word2vec models suing gensim on separate corpora.
Both corpora are in English.
In one corpus there are some different words which are not present in the other.

I want to map the common words of one model to the other.
Then I want to get the vectors of the unknown words (after the mapping).

I tried the following code:

```
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
from gensim.models import translation_matrix

w2v_bin_path_old    = 'model_from_corpus1_30d.bin'
w2v_bin_path_new    = 'model_from_corpus2_30d.bin'
wv_old              = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(w2v_bin_path_old, binary=True)
wv_new              = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(w2v_bin_path_new, binary=True)

common_tokens       = set(wv_old.vocab.keys()).intersection(set(wv_new.vocab.keys()))
common_tokens       = [(tok, tok) for tok in common_tokens]

transmat            = translation_matrix.TranslationMatrix(wv_new, wv_old, common_tokens)
transmat.train(common_tokens)

transmat.translate('whatever')
```

However, this code returns only the top 5 words from the destination w2v model. 
I only want to get the vector of the proposed token. 
Is there a way to do it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to just combine the two corpuses, and train a single model form the combined corpus? (In most situations involving the same language in both models, that'd be strictly better than the extra step of learning a best-guess translation function between two smaller corpuses.)

Comment: I have pre-trained models that work based on the vector space of the "wv_old" model. I want to project the new model to the old model to keep using the same pre-trained models. Re-training every pre-trained model needs resources and time.

Comment: Aha. I'll make some suggestions in an answer, but keep in mind that performing such translations likely won't be as good as re-training (even if it does save some marginal time/resources).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the `TranslationMatrix class isn't well-factored to let you just project vectors (the 1st step in its`.translate()`), rather than continue to do the full translations.

You'll want to do just a tiny subset of all the operations done by its actual `.translate()` method, whose source code can be viewed at:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/ec222e8e3e72608a59805040eadcf5c734a2b96c/gensim/models/translation_matrix.py#L279

More or less, you'd want to copy what this method does, but simply return the `mapped_source_space` (on line 345). It should have just the input ('source') words you've specified, and their new coordinates. (You can ignore all the branches having to do with the `gc=1` option or other frills.)

**Without having tested this code**, I think an external-to-the-translation-matrix utility method which does the right thing would be roughly:

```py
def project_words_vectors(translation_matrix, source_words):
    source_space = Space.build(translation_matrix.source_lang_vec, source_words)
    source_space.normalize()
    mapped_source_space = translation_matrix.apply_transmat(source_space)
    return mapped_source_space
```

(The returned `Space` object is a bit like a minimal `KeyedVectors` - and its `.index2word` list, and `.word2index` dict, serve as guides to which rows in its `.mat` property are which vectors. See the same source file linked above for more details.)

Let me know if this quick-and-dirty fragment works for your purposes, or needs any small fixes before it's usable.

(Separately, having looked over the original source code, I'm not certain the `.normalize()` in this function, or in the original `.translate()` method, or even in the original class `.train()` method, is strictly necessary for good results. If I were relying on this code, I'd test whether such train-time or translation-time normalization actually improves final results for my purposes of not.)